# Quitting Android App

Tags: android, operating-system, kill

I know this is a controversial subject and I know my reasons for wanting to quit my app aren't pure:

- The client wants the app to start from scratch after user has left for 15 minutes.
- The app is in beta, and in order to prevent tiny leaks from crashing the app in the long run, I want to kill the app (until I am sure none such exist)

I currently do a background call 15 minutes after the users leaves the app and I do:

```
this.finish();
System.exit(0);
```

This seems to work fine. Does this really kill the process completely? Please no "you shouldn't quit your app" lectures, I've already read through all those.

Comment: Even though you've heard the lectures, point one is a bad reason to do this.  Point two may be a more valid one.  (But there are much better ways to do point one...)

Comment: You might have read all the "you shouldn't quit your app" lectures, but you have not heeded the message. It is up to the Android OS to manage the lifecycle of your app. Give up your sinful ways before it is too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29):

> Causes the VM to stop running and the program to exit. If runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) has been previously invoked with a true argument, then all objects will be properly garbage-collected and finalized first.